# Export as .csv adds a lot of empty rows

Tags: excel, export

When I go to my last used cell, it goes to F222 and I don't know why. The cell is completly empty (no value or formulae) and its format is "General". The problem is now, when I save it as .csv file, it prints out a lot of empty rows like ",,,,,"

Comment: Can you share how you're finding this cell?

Comment: I find it with either with ctrl+END or with the selection with ctrl+Home then ctrl+shift+end

Comment: So this isnt to do with VBA?

Comment: I don't know actually. I can't find the reason for this issue..

Comment: I have a similar issue, though in my case I know there are formula in the empty cells.